# why the mail function not working

Tags: php

Why the mail function not sending mail to me ,Could any one please help me ?
Here i have wrote script to mail sending.
Is there any other settings to send mail. 
But the mail function printing always "Success" , but the mail not received to me.

```
$Msg = "Your Suggestion is saved successfully. Please wait for admin approval";
        $subject="New Suggestion Posted - Waiting for approval";

        //$email_id = 'bajrang.lal@sunarctechnologies.com';
        $email_id = 'bajrang.lal@sunarctechnologies.com';
        $mail_msg="Hello Admin,<br><br>New Suggestion Posted. Waiting for approval.<br><br>
         Suggestion : ".$frmdata['description']."<br><br> Click here for <a href='http://www.tatanykshipping.com/index.php'>login</a><br><br> Thanks,<br>The TATA NYK Team";  

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: Tata NYK <".$_SESSION['EMAIL_ID'].">\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Organization: Tata NYK\r\n";
        echo '<br>sending mail to = ',$email_id; 
        if(mail($email_id,$subject,$mail_msg,$headers))
          echo '<br>Successs';
        else 
          echo '<br>Fail';
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: what is the ouput you are getting? any error message?

Comment: No it prints "Successs" as i have printed.

Comment: In short, *sending* an e-mail doesn't guarantee delivery: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: are using this on windows or linux

Comment: You need to give more information about your server configuration. What operating system are you using? What are the settings in your php.ini file relating to email? This is likely to be a server configuration issue, as opposed to your code.

Comment: Check junk/spam box of the recipient

Comment: If you're testing this on your local dev machine you need to configure sendmail or some other mail server daemon for it to work.

Comment: not received in junk/spam box.

Comment: simple mail may not be supported on your live server. Try to use phpmailer and SMTP username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PHP application is running on Linux and expecting to send mail from that system, you need a transport. I use sendmail, but there are other open source transports you can use. You may also have to install an email client, but I do not know how PHP interacts with sending mail. My applications act like an email client, and need the email client installed.

You also need to make sure that the email recipient will accept unsolicited port 25 traffic. Because of spam-ware, our firewall won't accept unsolicited port 25 traffic, so I have doctored up sendmail to log into our email server as a legitimate email account.